# no matching function for call to '__darwin_fd_set' when building gem5 with X86 ISA

Tags: architecture, protocol-buffers, gem5

I am seeing an error when running the following scons command to get an X86 gem5 build

```
scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j 8
```

The error is :

```
    In file included from build/X86/arch/x86/linux/process.cc:51:
build/X86/sim/syscall_emul.hh:2375:13: error: no matching function for call to '__darwin_fd_set'
            FD_SET(trans_map[i], readfds);
```

This error doesn't show up when I'm building with build/ARM/gem5.opt, that build turned out just fine. I'm not sure what this is, can someone please help?